# fadeOut нативными средствами React с выполнением логики по завершению

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

Есть, скажем, такая кнопка:

```
import React from 'react';

import $ from 'jquery';

class LoggingButton extends React.Component {

  handleClick = () => {
    $('#div-welcome').fadeOut(400, () => {
      // что-то нехорошее делаем
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}  id="connect-button" className="default-button" >
        <span>Connect</span>
        <span id="loader"/>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default LoggingButton
```

Но для анимации используется jQuery, что совсем не React-way. Как сделать эту анимацию нативными средствами React'а с выполнением какой-то логики по завершению?

Чтобы работало и на нативных мобильных браузерах.

Comment: @Other это те Web анимации, которые работают только в Chrome и лишь частично в FF? Не подходит )

Comment: Это был намёк что надо погуглить. Я нашёл довольно много примеров, просто запросив их у всемогущего божества поиска.

Comment: @Other я тоже. Но почти все они работают только на версиях браузеров, которые вышли в последние год-два.

Comment: А что Вы хотели-то? Найти интерфейс, который за пару строк сделает всё и работать будет везде? Для старых нужно полифилл писать.

Comment: Я чужими фреймворками не пользуюсь, но просто логически рассуждая: взять код анимации из JQuery и вставить его в какой-нибудь отдельный компонент/модуль во фреймворке разве не вариант?

Comment: @Diskyp вариант, конечно. Просто есть вероятность, что выпиливание функционала из либы будет настолько сложным, что легче написать свою либу. Но во на счет кроссбраузерности можно будет забыть)

Comment: @Diskyp проблема тут в другом. Даже с jquery тут геморой с тем, что жизненный цикл react компонентов специфичный. Что будет, если компонент был выгружен, а таймер анимации всё ещё работает? В unmount вам, по-хорошему, нужно отменить анимацию, очистить таймер и т.п. В общем, что с jq, что без, не так всё просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про нативные средства React для анимаций ничего не знаю, но fadeOut тоже сойдет. Если его использовать правильно.

Во-первых, нельзя чтобы одним и тем же стилем управляли одновременно и React, и JQuery - а именно так сейчас и происходит. Вы делаете элементу fadeOut, но никогда не делаете ему fadeIn...

Во-вторых, ваш компонент с какого-то перепугу управляет совершенно левым элементом страницы который не он создавал. Это нарушает принцип изолированных компонентов, и ведет к потенциальным багам. Вместо этого следовало бы вызвать внешний обработчик, который изменит свойства отвечающего за анимацию компонента.

Ну и в-третьих, в идеологии React все переходы между состояниями UI должны делаться через изменение props, state или хотя бы через forceUpdate, но никак не в обработчике события.

Получается как-то так:

```
class DivWelcome extends React.Component {
    render() { ... }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        if (this.props.visible && !prevProps.visible)
            $this.fadeIn();
        else if (!this.props.visible && prevProps.visible)
            $this.fadeOut();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        if (this.props.visible)
            $this.show(); // или fadeIn, зависит от того что нужно получить
        else if (!this.props.visible)
            $this.hide(); // или fadeOut, зависит от того что нужно получить
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        const $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        $this.stop();
    }
}

class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.handleClick} className="default-button">
        <span>Connect</span>
        <span/>
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = { welcomeVisible: true };
    }

    handleClick = () => setState({ welcomeVisible: false });

    render() {
        return [
            <DivWelcome visible={this.state.welcomeVisible} />,
            <LoggingButton handleClick={this.handleClick} />,
        ]
    }
}
```

*PS код не проверял, и вообще я на реакте никогда не писал, так что относитесь к ответу с осторожностью*

Comment: А без участия `App` как-то можно? Чтоб `DivWelcome` сам подписался как-то на событие `onClick` кнопки?

Comment: @Suvitruf если без участия App - то нужна любая реализация EventBus либо библиотека для управления глобальным состоянием (redux, mobx, можно еще rx.js попробовать).

Comment: Хоть ваш ответ совсем не про fadeOut, но на полезные мысли натолкнул)